# Ursprung des Ausspruchs "die Spendierhosen anhaben"?

Tags: etymology

Wenn jemand gerade sehr spendabel oder freigiebig ist, kann man im Deutschen sagen, **er/sie hat gerade die Spendierhosen an**.

*Ich möchte wissen, woher dieser Ausdruck ursprünglich kommt.*

Was hat Großzügigkeit mit einer Hose zu tun? Gab es vielleicht früher eine spezielle Hosenform, die Reichen vorbehalten war, und wer so eine Hose anhatte, hatte auch Geld darin (das er spenden *hätte* können)? Oder ging es vielleicht ursprünglich gar nicht um eine Hose, sondern um ein anderes, ähnlich klingendes Wort, das ausgestorben ist?

Comment: 2. Google-Treffer sagt: *Diese Redensart findet sich schon im 17. Jahrhundert bei Abraham a Sancta Clara (Narrennest II, 37). Die Freigiebigkeit wird in ihr als eine Eigenschaft des Gewandes und nicht als eine charakterliche Tugend gesehen.* Leider fehlt eine weitere Quellenangabe.

Comment: @dakab y u no Antwort statt Kommentar?

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu: Zu wenig Substanz, zu wenig Alternativen, zu wenig Bequellung `;-)`

Comment: @dakab Papperlapapp ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Man weiß es nicht

Leider ist zur Etymologie der möglicherweise schon im 17. Jahrhundert, spätestens jedoch im frühen 18. Jahrhundert, gebräuchlichen Wendung "die Spendierhosen anhaben", die schon damals für jemanden, der aus einer Laune heraus freizügig ist, verwendet wurde, nichts bekannt.

#### Abraham a Sancta Clara?

Vereinzelt gibt es die Auffassung, dass diese Wendung auf den ursprünglich schwäbischen, dann aber in Wien tätigen Prediger [Abraham a Sancta Clara](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_a_Sancta_Clara) zurückgehe, der diesen Begriff in seinem 1703 entstandenen Werk ["Wunderlicher Traum von einem großen Narrennest"](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/wunderlicher-traum-von-einem-grossen-narrennest-4076/1) erstmalig benutzt haben soll. Wenn man das oben verlinkte digitale Transkript durchliest, findet man diesen Begriff aber nicht. Man muss also davon ausgehen, dass es sich hier um eine **falsche** Fährte handelt, doch könnte es schon sein, dass der für seinen Witz bekannte Prediger den Begriff scherzhaft verwendet haben mag (wenn auch nicht im o.g. Werk):

> Witzig ist auch noch, dass nicht die Charaktereigenschaft eines Menschen (Freizügigkeit, Großzügigkeit ...), sondern 'Hosen' als Grund für Freigiebigkeit angenommen werden! <sup>[Wispor](http://www.wispor.de/wp-red-s.htm)</sup>

#### Wahrscheinlich schon im 17. Jahrhundert bekannt

Bereits im frühen 18. Jahrhundert taucht der Begriff in einzelnen Wörterbüchern auf. So referenziert der [Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Gliederung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GS33899#XGS33899) auf das deutsch-italienische Wörterbuch aus 1702 von [Matthias Kramer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthias_Kramer) und auch im deutsch-holländischen Wörterbuch von Abrahamus van Moerbeck (1768) gibt es die [Spendierhosen](https://books.google.de/books?id=TXITAAAAQAAJ&dq=spendirhosen&pg=PA316#v=onepage&q=spendirhosen&f=false).

Ohne eine Referenz wird vereinzelt [vermutet](http://www.wispor.de/wp-red-s.htm), dass diese Scherzbezeichnung von Studenten im 17. Jahrhundert verbreitet wurde.

#### Aus dem Niederdeutschen?

Interessanterweise gibt es die *Spendierhose* aber auch im Niederdeutschen, wo sie [Spendi(e)rbuxen](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Gliederung&lemid=GS33894#XGS33894) oder [Spenderbücks'n](https://books.google.de/books?id=XSVbAAAAQAAJ&lpg=PA203&ots=q7ifiBUXUS&dq=Spendirhosen&pg=PA203#v=onepage&q=Spendirhosen&f=false) heißen. Dies wirft die Frage auf, ob der Begriff eventuell von dort in das Neuhochdeutsche übertragen wurde, möglicherweise mit einer scherzhaften Anspielung auf eine **Spendenbüchse**. Auch das ist aber nicht belegt.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for not posting in German, my knowledge is read-only, and hardly that. Anyway, in the book Teutsche Winter-Nächte by Johann Beer chapter 14 you can read "Verba neutra: Diejenigen Leute, quae servitium ad significant, welche gern einen Dienst hätten, dativum adsciscunt, müssen die Spendierhosen anlegen" and again in chapter 45. This book seems to be from 1682. http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/-8514/14

Comment: Das ist die bislang älteste Quelle, klingt aber, als sei es da schon ein etablierter Begriff. Damit gibt es aber eine zeitliche Richtung vor, in der man den Ursprung zu suchen hätte, und schränkt die Möglichkeit, dass das Wort einer sprachlichen Transformation zu verdanken ist, auch deutlich ein.

Comment: Spanderbukser/Spenderbukser is in use in Norwegian/Danish as well, probably imported from Niederdeutsch (as is the word Bukser/Buck-hose). Earliest finding is in Hørning: Liden Moralsk og Politisk Bibel, 1709, as "naar du længe har havt dine Spendeer-Buxer paa, og der er ikke meere Penge udi dem, see saa, om der er nogen der vil spendere paa dig igien". (After wearing your "spendierhosen" for long and they're empty for money, see if not someone would like to "spender" some on you). What would be a decent translation of this amusing word to English?

Answer (score 4):

> Wenn jemand in Geberlaune ist, dann freut sich alle Welt, jedenfalls
>   die Eingeladenen. Weil das nicht so häufig vorkommt, jedenfalls nicht
>   so häufig, wie man es sich wünscht, suchte man – scherzhaft – nach
>   Erklärungen für die Freigebigkeit und fand sie nicht im Charakter,
>   sondern in den besonderen Beinkleidern, die den Spendierer in die
>   entsprechende Laune versetzten.

(siehe hier: http://www.deutschlandradiokultur.de/die-spendierhosen-anhaben.1306.de.html?dram:article_id=193551)

Comment: Willkommen beim StackExchange für die Deutsche Sprache. Wenn Du Fragen hast, kannst Du Dir die [tour] und den [help] ansehen, oder Du schaust im Chat vorbei, sobald Du genügend "Reputation" angesammelt hast. Viel Spaß :)

Comment: Hast Du einen Clown gefrühstückt?